# StackImbalance MDA exception using stdcall calling conversion on both sides

Tags: c#, pinvoke, native-code, calling-convention

I got [pInvokeStackImbalance MDA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0htdy0k3(v=VS.100).aspx) for some unclear reason

Native code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) __declspec(noinline)  void __stdcall 
Ex(__int64 mask, unsigned long *index)
{
    *index = mask;
}
```

Managed:

```
[DllImport("Libr.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Ex(long mask, out uint index);
```

...

```
        uint val;
        long mask = 12;
        NativeWrapper.Ex(mask, out val); // pInvokeStackImbalance MDA here
```

So as you can see CallingConvention StdCall is using.. what is the reason of that warning here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The native function return type is `void` but your C# code returns `int`.